# How to upload image with express-fileupload from CKEditor5 properly?

Tags: express, ckeditor

My api as follows

```
router.post("/upload", async (req, res) => {
if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
return res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
}
console.log(req.files)
let file = req.files.upload;
let uploadPath = __dirname + "/../public/" + file.name;
file.mv(uploadPath, function (err) {
if (err) {
console.log(err)
return res.status(500).send(err)
}
res.sendStatus(200);
});
});
```

My react component

```
<CKEditor
editor={ClassicEditor}
config={{
ckfinder: {
uploadUrl: "/api/upload",
},
}}
data={props.state.tech.assess_info}
onChange={(event, editor) => {
..
}}
/>
```

Currently when I upload image from CKeditor, image is successfully uploaded(written to "public/{filename}" on server side). However CKEditor error popups and stating "cannot upload". I believe CKeditor is expecting specific response code, not just HTTP status 200. What do you guys think?

Comment: try ```res.status(200).json("OK")``` instead of ```res.sendStatus(200);```

Answer (score 0):

Ckeditor is expecting following response from API.

```
res.status(200).json({
      uploaded: true,
      url: `/uploads/${file.name}`,
    });
```

Whole api code if anyone needs.

```
// Upload a file
router.post("/upload", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
  }
  let file = req.files.upload;
  let uploadPath = __dirname + "/../public/uploads/" + file.name;
  file.mv(uploadPath, function (err) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
    res.status(200).json({
      uploaded: true,
      url: `/uploads/${file.name}`,
    });
  });
});
```